# Select нескольких значений в query where php, пробразовать строку

Tags: php, запрос, select

Есть фильтр, на данный момент есть задача - убрать из range цену, которая не входит (или выходит за пределы) фильтрованных полей.
На примере поля Vendor - производитель

```
$all_prices = $nc_core->db->get_results("SELECT Price FROM 'Message$classID' WHERE 'Checked' = 1 AND 'Subdivision_ID' = ".$sub." AND 'Vendor' = '". $VendorRang[$j] . "'", ARRAY_A );
```

Но при выборе двух произволителей, строка `$VendorRang[$j]` страновится такого вида: SamsungApple . 
В итоге два вопроса:

1) Можно ли SamsungApple разделить на два слова, чтобы применить `AND 'Vendor' IN`
2) Или есть другой, более удобный/быстрый/верный вариант решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Откуда вы получаете значение в $VendorRang[$j] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли SamsungApple разделить на два слова, чтобы применить AND 'Vendor' IN

Если `$VendorRang[$j]` принимает вид строки `SamsungApple` то её можно разбить на массив слов используя look ahead выражение:

```
$array = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $VendorRang[$j]);
```

и дальше сделать из массива строку с разделителем в виде запятой:

```
implode("','", $array );
```

Получается как-то так:

```
$vendors = implode(",", preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $VendorRang[$j]) );
$all_prices = $nc_core->db->get_results("SELECT Price FROM 'Message$classID' WHERE 'Checked' = 1 AND 'Subdivision_ID' = ".$sub." AND 'Vendor' IN ('". $vendors  . "')", ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Почему-то  var_dump($all_prices) возвращает NULL, хотя echo $vendors корректный, с запятой

Comment: Так и сделала, спасибо огромное, получилось -  в запросе было ('Brend1,Brend2,Brend3'), обернула каждый в кавычки и все получилось